# Highchart not resize properly in angular js

Tags: css, angularjs, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to show some statistics in my app using angularjs. Graph loads fine when the page gets loaded.

When I change the orientation, [it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu7Xt.jpg)

and when again I change the orientation from landscape to portrait it [some thing looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By8kM.jpg)

I tried to change css in many way but it not fit on full screen every time. Does any one know why highchart not respond to orientation change ?

EDIT: Code snippet

```js
var chart1 = new Highcharts.chart('demograph', {
          
          "options": {
           "chart": {
             "type": "areaspline"
             
           },
           "plotOptions": {
             "series": {
               "stacking": ""
             }
           }
         },
         "series": [
           {
             "name": "Highest",
             "data": [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
             "type": "column",
             "id": "series-0"
           },
           {
             "name": "Lowest",
             "data": [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5],
             "type": "column",
             "id": "series-1"
           },
           {
             "name": "Average",
             "data": [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0],
             "type": "column",
             "id": "series-2"
           },
           {
             "name": 'Louis',
             "data": [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8],
             "id": "series-3",
             "type": "line"
           }
         ],
         "title": {
           "text": "Progress Report"
         },
         "credits": {
           "enabled": true
         },
         "loading": false,
         "size": {},
         "xAxis": {
           "categories": ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
           "title": {text: 'Tests'}
          },
          "yAxis": {
           "title": {text: 'Marks Obtained'}
          },
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 myclass2" style="">
  <div id="demograph" class="clsdemograph" >Placeholder for chart</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the demo code html/css that you're using? you can use jsfiddle for this

Comment: Actually it some what complicated to add code as it is dynamic content and css as well so I was not added it. But let me try if I can provide some piece of code.

Comment: @shershen. Added demo code. Please check.

Comment: If chart is not taking size of it's resized container then you could call [chart.reflow()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow) Also, it would be useful to find out why is the chart not resizing, but when using your demo I was unable to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below code?

```
<div id="demograph" class="clsdemograph" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;">Placeholder for chart</div>
```